# Laravel: how can I get browser cache in this function?

Tags: php, image, laravel, caching, browser

I have a controller that serves images from my Laravel storage folder:

```
public function showPhoto($filename)
{
    return Image::make(storage_path('app/images/' . $filename))->response();
}
```

My question: How can I enable browser cache for this images? 
I have seen the package `intervention/imagecache`, but I doesn't mean server cache.

I have changed things like response status 304, but that doesn't work. How can I have browser cache for this images?

Comment: You need to send few headers along with the image as response. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, you simply need to add `setClientTtl($cacheInSeconds)` at the end of your call, like so:

```
return Image::make(storage_path('app/images/' . $filename))
    ->response()
    ->setClientTtl(60 * 60 * 24 * 7); // cache for 1 week
```